# keep column names when applying as.vector to a matrix slice

Tags: r, slice, default-value, matrix-indexing, r-colnames

Let us say I have a matrix,

```
A = matrix(c(1,23,4,5,6,3,2,2,1,2), nrow = 2, ncol = 5)
```

with rownames and column names given by,

```
rownames(A) = c('row1', 'row2')
colnames(A) = c('es', 'one', 'column', 'no', '5')
```

If I do:

```
> my.slice = A[1,,drop=FALSE]
    es    one column     no      5 
     1      4      6      2      1
```

I still see the column names.  But if I do:

```
> my.slice = as.numeric(A[1,,drop=FALSE])
[1] 1 4 6 2 1
```

I lost the column names, and both are actually of numeric class.

Is there a way to do as.vector and keep the column names?  Or more generally, to slice the matrix into a numeric class vector with names(my.slice) = colnames(A)?

It all started when I set up the default to be `drop=FALSE`.  Then I need to do as.vector when i slice matrices but sadly now I loose the names of the elements in my.slice.

Comment: `is.vector(A[1,])` returns `TRUE`, primarily because `[` has `drop=TRUE` set by default. Try `dput(A[1,])` you'll see it is just a vector with some names attached.

Comment: @thelatemail thanks. that's a nice answer but I am looking for a short one that keeps me in the numeric class since all my code is built into operations in that class.

Comment: It **is** numeric - `is.numeric(A[1,])` == `TRUE`

Comment: @thelatemail it's nice. some follow up Qs, can I turn off the printing behavior? and is it as fast as as.vector? I am using as.vector in for loops so having this print the structure to the screen makes it inconvenient.  Other than that looks like a good way to go

Comment: I'm getting confused here. Subsetting one row will give you a vector with names - `as.vector` is not required.

Comment: Don't do that then. Overriding defaults is a first class way to balls up your code.

Comment: setNames(as.numeric(A[1,,drop=F]),colnames(A))
    es    one column     no      5 
     1      4      6      2      1

Comment: @Dnaiel: don't change the default, it potentially breaks all packages relying on normal behavior. Don't do it, bro. Especially if our need is only for pretty-printing. Leave the default behavior, write a formatting function instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the matrix to a data frame, slice it, and use `unlist` to make the slice into a named vector:

> `B <- as.data.frame(A)`
>
> `my.slice <- unlist(B[1,])`

This works as long as the column names do not contain strange characters: the column names of a data frame must be syntactically acceptable as the names of variables, so they can't begin with numbers or punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`setNames`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/setNames.html):

```
(my.slice = setNames(A[1,], colnames(A)))
es    one column     no      5 
 1      4      6      2      1 

class(my.slice)
[1] "numeric"
```